# calculate selected time is greater than or less than current time

Tags: php

Iam doing a genreal greater than less than time calculation in php, it works well when:

```
$a = "10:00am"; // say selected time1
$b = "10:15am"; //say current time
$c = "10:30am"; // say selected time2
if($b>$a && $b<$c){
 echo "YES"; // This is the result, which is correct
}else{
echo "NO";
}
```

But If I change time Like this, in this case result is "NO", can anyone explain why?:

```
    $a = "9:00am"; // say selected time1
    $b = "10:00am"; //say current time
    $c = "11:30am"; // say selected time2
    if($b>$a && $b<$c){
     echo "YES";
    }else{
    echo "NO"; // This is the result, which is not correct
    }
```

Comment: You are comparing strings so lexically `9:00am` is greater than `10:00am` (because `9` > `1`). You may use some Date functions (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) to parse and compare this time values.

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
$a = strtotime("9:00am"); // say selected time1
$b = strtotime("10:00am"); //say current time
$c = strtotime("11:30am"); // say selected time2
if($b>$a && $b<$c){
 echo "YES";
}else{
echo "NO"; // This is the result, which is not correct
}
```

Output :

```
YES
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created below code to check current time is greater than other time. Please check this code.

```
if(strtotime(date('H:i:s')) > strtotime(date('10:00:00'))){
  echo 'Greater than 10 AM';
}
else{
  echo 'Less than 10 AM';
}
```

Otherwise you can use this code, for 24 hour format

```
if(date("G") >= 10)      
{
  echo 'current time is greater than 10:00 AM';
}
```